# How do I change the default database on postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

It seems to me that Postgres is ignoring my envar and the sql script

Here's my docker-compose

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      POSTGRES_DB: ecommerce
    volumes:
      - /custom/mount:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./sql_script.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sql_script.sql
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

In the doc is saying that I can change the default database name using **POSTGRES_DB**  env var but is not working for me. At first my intention was to create the database using a **sql_script.sql** through volumes, got it from the doc as well but didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `POSTGRES_DB` (and the other variables) are only relevant when the data directory is initially empty. If a postgres database already exists, it will be used as it is. Make sure that `/custom/mount` is empty.

Comment: The server does not have a default database.  The client always specifies the database it wants to connect to.  The client library has methods for making that choice if one is not specified, but those methods don't involve consulting with the server.  POSTGRES_DB specifies what database should be initially created, but that doesn't set it to be the default.

Comment: "but is not working for me"  That is not an adequate description.

Comment: @larsks thanks you man, I have thought that data in this path was deleted when I removed the volume. I've changed the path, and it solved.

Answer (score 0):

The `POSTGRES_DB` variable is only used if your `/custom/mount` directory is empty. If it already contains a database, the variable isn't used.

From the docs:

> Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you
> start the container with a data directory that is empty; any
> pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

Delete the contents of the directory and run your container again, and it should create the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the **POSTGRES_DB** variable to create a new database even if the `/custom/mount` directory already contains a database, you can modify the startup process of the PostgreSQL container.  [PGSQL Docker Documentation](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-the-postgres-docker-official-image/)